# multiple schemas in same .xjb for maven-jaxb21-plugin

Tags: xsd, maven-jaxb2-plugin, multiple-schema

I'm trying to use `inheritance` option using `jaxb2-commons` and it works fine for *one* schema specified in the maven plugin. But if I add another schema to same .xjb file, the pom.xml shows error as `Unable to parse schemas exception`.

I suspected that it could be because both the schema have same `targetnamespace`and tried to provide different namespace and that seems to work.

So is it possible to keep the same targetnamespace for 2 different xsd (in my case it is just 2 different versions of xsd so it makes sense to have same targetnamespace).  Any ideas ? any other possible solution ?

EDIT : I added 2 `execution` inside the `plugin` and it fails with `Unable to parse schemas exception` as well.

**common.xjb**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
    jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">

    <!-- ================================================================ -->

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="product_1_0.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='product']">
            <jxb:class name="ProductModel" />
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="product_1_0.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="org.doc.model" />
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="product_1_0.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='product']">
            <inheritance:extends>org.doc.model.AbstractProduct
            </inheritance:extends>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <!-- ================================================================ -->
   <!-- if I add below, this fails and shows error in pom.xml  -->
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="product_1_1.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='product']">
            <jxb:class name="ProductModel_1_1" />
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb21-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xsdgen-JAXB</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <includeSchema>*.xsd</includeSchema>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <xjbSources>common.xjb</xjbSources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xsimplify</arg>
            <arg>-Xinheritance</arg>
        </args>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I had managed resolve by adding two different `<execution>` and providing only the related schema and `.xjb` bindings file for respective `<execution>`. But the problem with this approach is that for *n* `.xsd`, there is *n* `.xjb`.

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>xsdgen-JAXB</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>product_1_0.xsd</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <bindingIncludes>
                        <include>product_1_0.xjb</include>
                </bindingIncludes>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
     <execution>
        <id>xsdgen-JAXB-2</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>product_1_1.xsd</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <bindingIncludes>
                    <include>product_1_1.xjb</include>
                </bindingIncludes>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```